# Cannot start apache (Unable to change directory to /root)

Tags: apache-2.2, root, start

When trying to start Apache by using:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd start
```

I get the following error in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`:

```
Unable to change directory to /root
```

Anyone have any idea what this means?

Comment: Where do you get the error (stderr, syslog, ...) and how are you starting it?

Comment: I start with command `/etc/init.d/httpd start`, I get the error in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`

Comment: Is your apache conf some vanilla packaged default, or have you customised it in any way; is this a source install or an OS package, or what?

Comment: it is freshly installed centos 6. I didn't touch apache conf.

Comment: Is there a `ChrootDir` directive in your `http.conf` file (or one of the million other files CentOS uses to configure Apache)?

Comment: @Chris S, I couldn't find such directive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its SELinux.

because you have it enabled, you need to start service using

```
service httpd start
```

edit your SELinux config and either disable it or set it to permissive:

> nano /etc/sysconfig/selinux

```
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#       enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#       permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#       disabled - SELinux is fully disabled.
SELINUX=disabled
```

Once changed then you will be able to start httpd using:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd start
```

If you need to keep SELinux enabled, then just use the service script to start/stop/restart the service.

```
# service httpd start/stop/restart
```

Answer (score 0):

The ServerRoot has apparently not been set (properly.)

If unset, this default to $HOME.

Edit httpd.conf and set a proper ServerRoot (usually /etc/httpd or /etc/apache2.)

Comment: ServerRoot is set as "/etc/httpd"

Comment: Use `apachectl start` instead.

Comment: still getting the same error

Comment: @marvin Can you post the output of apachectl configtest ?

Comment: `[Wed Mar 21 11:53:42 2012] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Wed Mar 21 11:53:42 2012] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Wed Mar 21 11:53:42 2012] [error] Unable to change directory to /root`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it without disabling SELinux, then don't try to run http start/stop command inside /root directory.

This is temporary fix but always work, just switch to /tmp (cd /tmp) and run the command to start apache (/etc/init.d/httpd start)